# OnItemClickListener - Error: There is no argument given that corresponds

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, onclicklistener

Could you explain me what is wrong with this code?

```
 private void HandleEvents()
    {
        mListView.ItemClick += mListView_ItemClick;
    }

    void mListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

        mListView_OnItemClickListener();
    }

    void mListView_OnItemClickListener(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Testo.Text = (parent.GetItemIdAtPosition(position).ToString());
    }
```

I get this error:

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'parent' of 'MainActivity.mListView_OnItemClickListener(AdapterView, View, int, long)'

Thanks!

Comment: your method expects four parameters, while when calling you pass none of them

Comment: Question 1: What are the arguments a caller of the method mListView_OnItemClickListener has to provide? Question 2: Which arguments do you provide in your call to mListView_OnItemClickListener inside the method mListView_ItemClick? Question 3: What part of the error message was unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use

```
AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs
```

you should have

```
e.Position
```

that should give you the Selected Position in "fermate".

So you can use something like

```
void mListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{

    Testo.Text = fermate[e.Position];
}
```